# ¿Como puedo enseñar y ocultar labels?

Tags: swift, swift4

Buen día, soy algo nuevo en esto y tengo una duda que me ha atorado.

Tengo 4 labels (dayString1, dayString2, dayString3 y dayString4) en los cuales les meterán un valor numérico y lo que necesito hacer es que si el contenido de dayString1 es menor que 60 que aparezca el dayString2, y si la suma de dayString1 + dayString2 es menor a 60 aparezca el dayString3 y así sucesivamente; mi lógica era la siguiente, pero me da error.
De ante mano gracias.

```
func chooseDays() {
    self.dayString = dayTextField.text!
    self.dayString2 = dayTextField2.text!
    self.dayString3 = dayTextField3.text!
    self.dayString4 = dayTextField4.text!

    if dayString < 60 {
        self.dateTextField2.isHidden = false
        self.dayTextField2.isHidden = false

        self.dateTextField3.isHidden = true
        self.dayTextField3.isHidden = true
        self.dateTextField4.isHidden = true
        self.dayTextField4.isHidden = true

        SearchConstraint.constant = 72

        if dayString + dayString2 < 60 {
            self.dateTextField2.isHidden = false
            self.dayTextField2.isHidden = false
            self.dateTextField3.isHidden = false
            self.dayTextField3.isHidden = false

            self.dateTextField4.isHidden = true
            self.dayTextField4.isHidden = true

            SearchConstraint.constant = 112

            if dayString + dayString2 + dayString3 < 60 {
                self.dateTextField2.isHidden = false
                self.dayTextField2.isHidden = false
                self.dateTextField3.isHidden = false
                self.dayTextField3.isHidden = false
                self.dateTextField4.isHidden = false
                self.dayTextField4.isHidden = false

                SearchConstraint.constant = 152
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero estar entiendo la pregunta bien.

La función la empiezas con:

```
self.dayString = dayTextField.text!
```

Lo cual me da a entender que las variables `dayString, dayString2, dayString3, dayString4` son de tipo `String`.

Después sigues con:

```
if dayString < 60 {
```

Donde estás usando el operador `<` para comparar un `String` (dayString) con un `Int` (60). El error que te marca tal vez sea este:

[image: error de compilación]

(yo lo recreé en un playground, tal vez no sea exactamente ese).

Para resolverlo, podrías agregar un `guard` donde hagas el cast a `Int` y salir, de esta forma:

```
func chooseDays() {

    guard
        let dayString = Int(dayString),
        let dayString2 = Int(dayString2),
        let dayString3 = Int(dayString3),
        let dayString4 = Int(dayString4)
        else { return }

    if dayString < 60 {
        //el código que ya tenías
    }
}
```

En este caso no se maneja la situación que la cadena en cuestión no se pueda parsear a entero, simplemente se retorna de la función. Si necesitas manejar este caso de otra manera (que es lo más seguro) tal vez que convenga otra estrategia.

Comment: ya lo hice y no da ningún error pero tampoco funciona, alguna sugerencia de el porque no funciona?

Comment: Probablemente algún `dayString` no se pudo parsear a entero. Sugiero que hagas un print antes del return del guard para verificarlo. Si la ejecución llega a `if dayString < 60 {` el problema está en otro lado.